# Import testnet address in bcoin

Tags: testnet, import, watch-only

I´m trying to import a watch-only address to my bcoin node using cli (testnet). My config looks as follows:

```
[....]
#
# Options
#

network: testnet

#
# Node
#

prefix: ~/.bcoin-testnet
db: leveldb
max-files: 64
cache-size: 100
[...]
```

entering the following command (just a random valid testnet address):

```
 bcoin wallet watch my7q4nhpuJ6TsevXdDnPRq1rvHcPKeGEaD
```

results with the following error in the `debug.log`:

```
[E:2017-08-03T08:43:02Z] (node) Network mismatch for address.
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Network mismatch for address.
at Wallet.importAddress [as _importAddress] ([...]/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/lib/node_modules/bcoin/lib/wallet/wallet.js:1310:3)
at Wallet.importAddress ([...]/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/lib/node_modules/bcoin/lib/wallet/wallet.js:1284:23)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
[E:2017-08-03T08:43:02Z] (node) This socket is closed
Error: This socket is closed
at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:721:18)
at Socket._write (net.js:781:8)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:371:12)
at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:497:7)
at Socket.Writable.uncork (_stream_writable.js:297:7)
at connectionCorkNT (_http_outgoing.js:695:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

The error occurs, no matter what address I try to import. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the http api to perform an import. Notably, you import a wallet with the create wallet command as the import command imports addresses into a wallet.

`curl -X PUT \
  http://127.0.0.1:18332/wallet/$ID \
  -H 'authorization: Basic eDppYW1zYXRvc2hp' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "masterKey":$MASTERKEY
}'`

[Link to docs](https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin/wiki/REST-&-RPC-API#put-walletid)